# Compilation scheme of generics

Tags: c#, generics

how generic types work in c#? Any link from where I could read detailed explanation of the same will be useful. Basically I need to learn about compilation scheme and role of JIT compiler. I know upper crux of Generics and their benefits but I want to know how they are handled by compiler in comparison to other System.Collection namespace classes.

Comment: @Heandel I need to know how generic types are handled by the compiler. It is said that generic avoid code bloat. Also I read that generics uses code sharing mechanism to reduce the amount of code generated for generic types. I want to know how this all is achieved by using Generic collection. A little light over IL code generation for generics will help. As I said earlier, I need to know behind the scene activities by compiler in handling Generic Collection which differentiates them from Collections.I hope now my question might be clearer to you. And thanks for not voting it down.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN, An Introduction to C# Generics - What Are Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx#csharp_generics_topic2)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use the same code for different types at that point we prefer to use **Generics**.You can refer this link to know exactly how generics are processed and excuted.  [Compilation of Generics](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlos/2009/11/09/net-generics-and-code-bloat-or-its-lack-thereof/)